# How to mutate apollo context in next.js?

Tags: apollo, next.js

I've looked in to [api-routes-apollo-server-and-client-auth](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client-auth) example and not sure how can i mutate context both on ssr and client request.

I want for every graphql resolver (using api) have access to ctx.user object with preparsed JWT token. But where should i parse it?

If i parse it here:

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context(ctx) {
    ctx.user = '123'
    return ctx
  }
})

export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' })
```

Then ctx.user will be undefined on SSR request, working only on client request.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
// server
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async () => {
    const jwt = req.headers.authorization
    const user = await getUserFromJwt(jwt)
    return {
      user,
    }
  }
})

// client
const link = createHttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost...' })
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: jwt,
    },
  }
})    

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(link),
  ...
})
```

Check out these docs: [client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/) and [server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/)